# Unable to use swap without temparary variable

Tags: c++, quicksort

**Quick sort program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// constant
enum {MAX = 10};

// class
class A
{
private:
    int arr[MAX];
public:
    A() // constructor
    {
        srand(time(0));
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
            arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    // accessing array
    int get(int i)
    {
       return arr[i];
    }
    // quick sort
    int Partition(int left, int right);
    void quickSort(int left, int right);
    void Swap(int&, int&);
};

// member function definition
int A::Partition(int left, int right)
{
    int pivot = arr[right], i = left - 1;
    for(int j = left; j <= right-1; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j] < pivot)
        {
            i++;
            Swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
        }
    }
    Swap(arr[i+1], arr[right]);
    return i+1;
}

void A::quickSort(int left, int right)
{
    if(left < right)
    {
        int pi = Partition(left, right);
        quickSort(left, pi-1);
        quickSort(pi+1, right);
    }
}

void A::Swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    a = a+b;
    b = a-b;
    a = a-b;
}

// driver
int main(void)
{
    A obj1;

    //-------Array initialized--------
    cout << "Before sorting:" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        cout << setw(4) << obj1.get(i);

    //--------Sorting Array-----------
    obj1.quickSort(0, MAX-1);

    //--------Sorted Array------------
    cout << "\nAfter sorting:" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        cout << setw(4) << obj1.get(i);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is inside the swap() function. When I am swapping the values using a int temp variable, values gets swapped and array gets sorted in ascending order.

But when I am swapping the values without using a temporary int variable, I'm getting 0s in the sorted array. As shown below:

**Output**

```
Before sorting:
   89   43   18   98   23   88   52   18   1   25
After sorting:
   1   18   0   0   25   43   0   88   89   98
```

Comment: I'd suspect that the issue is not with swap, but with Undefined Behaviour somewhere else in the code. It just manifests itself based on one or the other implementation.

Comment: Swapping with arithmetic hasn't been an efficient method since flared jeans went out of style the first time.

Comment: All those `+ 1` and `- 1` adjustments make it very unlikely that you don't have an off-by-one error somewhere. The conventional half-open intervals are conventional for good reasons, one of them being how much nicer it becomes to divide intervals. (Also: testing with random numbers is a bad idea unless you reuse the seed. Test cases should be small and systematic, not large and arbitrary.)

Comment: Just use `std::swap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not because of swap, it arises from the calling function that has send a same variable to be swap. This causes the arithmetic to give zero for `a-b`.

In the following code:

```
int A::Partition(int left, int right)
{
    int pivot = arr[right], i = left - 1;
    for(int j = left; j <= right-1; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j] < pivot)
        {
            i++;
            Swap(arr[i], arr[j]); // i = j in the first run
    }
}
   Swap(arr[i+1], arr[right]); // here also exists case that i+1 = right
   return i+1;
}
```

For a test: Using if condition to filter the colliding indexes, it works:

```
 if (i != j)Swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
```

and

```
 if ((i+1) != right) Swap(arr[i+1], arr[right]);
```